# Git rebase merges instead of replaying on top

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I'm on Git 2. Something during the last 1.5 years must have changed in Git. 
When I now rebase (git checkout mybranch; git rebase master) I expect Git to replay the commits of mybranch onto master, like in the Git book at git-scm.com. Instead it merges master into mybranch and I lose some of my changes in mybranch. 
What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to tell Git to do it as expected?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post some log? It doesn't sound right.

Comment: Can you do a git pull --rebase master from your local branch and check what happens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the advice to try

```
git rebase master mybranch
```

This did the job for me.